# Vue/Axios CORS success but response empty

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, cors, axios

I have an Laravel API on my localhost:8000 and my Vue running on localhost:8080. I made CORS works using chrome extensions but this is just for development. Now I was trying to make a CORS request without that extension.

In laravel I use the barryvdh/laravel-cors package. Now my front-end accepts my OPTIONS request it does my GET request. Example:
[image]

[image]

So they BOTH get the ok status.

But here comes the problem, my reponse is empty: [image]

**AND** I still get an error about the cross allow origin: [image]

Now I know that my api works, because I have tested it with the extension making CORS works. Can someone explain to me about what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The OPTIONS response has the Access-Control headers on it, which allows the JavaScript to make the GET request.

The GET response **does not** have the Access-Control headers on it, so the JavaScript does not have permission to read the data in it.

Comment: so what should i do to add them, cause the headers are set from the server on every call?

Comment: "cause the headers are set from the server on every call" — They aren't. That is the problem. You need to fix the server.

Comment: I use laravel, i have the package barryvdh/laravel-cors. That has an config file that should add the header to every request. Its an middleware btw. Are you 
familiar with that package? (i have registered the middelware as global, so every route)

Comment: No, I am not. I know little about PHP.

Comment: You can enable it globally by applying it like the package explains: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors#global-usage If you don't it will ONLY add a global preflight, not the cors on each response.

Comment: thanks @Luceos, but yes I have done that already. Still no luck.